# Polimorfismo cast superclase a subclase

Tags: java

asignar una referencia a un objeto de una subclase a su superclase me funciona bien y entiendo el concepto.

Castear una referencia a un objeto de su superclase a una referencia de su subclase (más especifica) me genera una excepción de tipo ClassCastException. No se puede hacer nunca esto? Hay algún caso que tenga sentido?

Gracias.

Un cordial saludo

Comment: Nos muestras un ejemplo de lo que intentaste?? mira por favor [ask]

Comment: En líneas generales, la respuesta es: **si se puede**. Sin ver tu código, es difícil decir algo más específico. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4):

> Castear una referencia a un objeto de su superclase a una referencia
>   de su subclase (más especifica) me genera una excepción de tipo
>   ClassCastException. No se puede hacer nunca esto? Hay algún caso que
>   tenga sentido?

No se puede hacer porque una superclase **no es** una subclase (lo que sí se da en sentido inverso).

Sólo para distinguir, porque en los ejemplos en otras respuestas se está usando ejemplos que no son estrictamente super clases:

El casteo se puede hacer a una super clase o a una interface que el objeto implementa.

En el primer caso se puede hacer porque la subclase tiene todos los métodos y atributos de la super clase, lo que no se puede garantizar en en sentido inverso.

Y en el caso de la interface, al implementarla, tiene todos los métodos que la misma declara, lo que también podría no darse en sentido inverso (que la clase que la implementa tenga más métodos).

Por eso es que el casteo puede hacerse de lo más específico a lo menos y no al revés.

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, un ejemplo sencillo es la clase `List` de java

```
List<String> lista= new ArrayList<>();
lista=new LinkedList<>();
```

la clase generica viene a ser la clase `List`, y las subclases son las clases `ArrayList` y `LinkedList`

Comment: Creo que él esta preguntando realizar la referencia en sentido inverso, ósea un castear un List como ArrayList, algo que no se puede realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, si entiendes lo del `asignar una referencia de una subclase a un superclase`
a la hora de hacer un Cast puede haber problemas, ya que si la superclase posee más subclase pues tocaría de hacer algo más en el código, que sería manejar el uso de `instanceof` en condicionales. El uso de `instanceof` es averiguar si el objeto de una superclase es una instancia de una X subclase.

### Ejemplo de Uso

En este ejemplo, digamos que tenemos un método que nos devuelve un `List<String>` llamado `getList()` y queremos saber cual instancia es, por lo tanto usamos el uso de `instanceof` en un condicional `if`
mediante el uso del `instanceof` se hará

1. Si la variable no es nula, si lo es, dará como resultado false por lo tanto no sería necesario hacer `if (object != null)` en este tipo de caso
2. Si el objeto es una instancia que hemos especificado podremos hacer el Cast sin problemas

```
List<String> list = getList();
if (list instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) list;
} else if (list instanceof LinkedList) {
    LinkedList linkedList = (LinkedList) list;
}
```

Comment: Es al revés, un objeto ArrayList es a la vez un instanceof List porque implementa esa interface.

Comment: esta respuesta esta al reves

Comment: Uff, ya veo a lo que se refería, entonces como yo siendo usuario nuevo por llamarlo de nuevo forma, borro la respuesta o como hago?¿ Ya que la respuesta estaría equivocada :/